# What does this c code trying to do

Tags: c

What does the following c code trying to do. I am not sure what does it calculate the value of width to

```
(width+31)&~31
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It rounds `width` upwards to a multiple of 32.

Answer (score 4):

It is rounding up to the next multiple of 32.  It only works because 32 is a power of 2.

```
The bit pattern for  31 is ...000000000011111
The bit pattern for ~31 is ...111111111100000
```

When you and ~31 with any positive integer, you get a multiple of 32 (five low order bits are all zeroes).

Answer (score 0):

It resets (turns off) the last 5 bits of the 'width' which leads to width%32=0 i.e. width multiple of 32.